# How to access C properties?

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, swift

I'm working with the libxml2 framework in my swift code, and not sure what the proper syntax is to access the properties.

In Objective-C you can access the property with:

```
currentNode->name
```

But when trying to use the same syntax with Swift, I get this errors:

**"Braced block of statements is an unused closure"**

I'm guessing this is because "->" is already reserved.

I've also tried:

```
currentNode.name
```

But I get the error:

**"'xmlNodePtr' does not have a member named 'name'"**

Is it possible to access a C property in Swift?

Comment: Clarifying explanation: Those aren't really properties, at least not in the ObjC @property sense. The `->` is a combination pointer dereference and struct member access. So, really you've got a pointer to a struct, and need to dereference the pointer (to get the struct itself), then access the member(s) of the struct you're interested in. (I don't know how to do this in Swift, myself.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to do this is to use the `memory` variable of the `UnsafePointer` type.

To speed things up, however, my preferred way is to define a custom operator to dereference the `UnsafePointer` type:

```
operator postfix & { }

@postfix func &<T>(lhs: UnsafePointer<T>) -> T {
    return lhs.memory;
}
```

Once you have this, you can do the following:

```
let doc = xmlReadDoc(nil, "my-url", "UTF-8", 0);
let root = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);

var currentChild = root&.children;
while (currentChild != nil) {
    var str = String.fromCString(UnsafePointer<CChar>(currentChild&.name));
    println("Child name: \(str)");

    currentChild = currentChild&.next;
}
```

You could even make the result return a nullable if you'd like to allow for chaining.

Comment: Interesting solution. Note you don't have to use `UnsafePointer`, especially if you're constructing your own bridge routines around a window where you might be able to guarantee pointer safety — see `CMutablePointer<T>` and friends in the standard library.

Comment: @rickster That is correct, though OP specifically mentioned lxml2, so that's what my answer was geared towards.